# While..Do with multiple conditions in shell

Tags: shell, while-loop

I need to read a file line by line until end of file, or a blank line is encountered. I have the following code in a shell script which does not work:

```
while read line
do
    commands
done < file.prop || $line == ""
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this could be done easily with the `break` command.

```
while read line
do
    if [ "$line" == "" ]; then
        break
    else
        # commands
    fi
done < file.prop
```